# php: inserting line breaks between array_filter() values...?

Tags: php

I have the following concatenation method I am using to join `n` potentially "empty" (zero length) strings:

```
$joint_address = implode(",", array_filter([$joint_address_field_1, $joint_address_field_2, $joint_address_field_3, $joint_address_field_4, $joint_address_field_5, $joint_address_field_6]));
```

This variable then gets sent across to a PDF form field using `PDFM` and other such delights.

However, the client now wants this joint address to be line broken. How do I prepare this string to be line broken for a **PDF** field?

Do I somehow need to insert a "\r" carriage return for only the variables which have a length?

Comment: Did you try `\n`?

Comment: I have tried `$joint_address = implode(",\n", array_filter([...,...,...,...]));`

Answer (score 0):

How about enclosing it in html table and store that html table in variable

you will have to put this style in pdf view

```
  <style>
  .noborder{
        border:none;
  }
  .sticktogether{
       display: flow-root;
  }
  </style>
```

and now send the final_joint_address variable to pdf view

```
<?php
$joint_address_field_1 = "E/1/1 1-1";
$joint_address_field_2= "AAAAA 2";
$joint_address_field_3= "Near A B C";
$joint_address_field_4= "111111";
$joint_address_field_5= "C V B";
$joint_address_field_6= "VVVVVVVVV";


$joint_address = implode(",", array_filter([$joint_address_field_1, $joint_address_field_2, $joint_address_field_3, $joint_address_field_4, $joint_address_field_5, $joint_address_field_6]));

$addr_arr = explode(',',$joint_address);

$final_joint_address = "<table class='noborder'>";
$row = 0;
foreach($addr_arr as $key => $val )
{
    if($row == 0)
        $final_joint_address .= "<tr class='noborder sticktogether'>";

        $ifcomma =  $key == count($addr_arr) - 1 ? "":",";
        $final_joint_address .= "<td class='noborder'>$val $ifcomma</td>";

        if($row == 3 || $key ==(count($addr_arr) - 1)) //no of line breaks depends on "$row" value if $row = 3 will display 4 values seperated by commas as shown in results below in this case  
        {
            $final_joint_address .= "</tr>";
            $row = 0;
        }else
        {
            $row++;
        }

}
$final_joint_address .= "</table>";

echo $final_joint_address;
?>

//results : 
E/1/1 1-1 ,AAAAA 2 ,Near A B C ,111111 ,
C V B , VVVVVVVVV
```